# How to solve Manager peer problem using union-find approach?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was asked this question in an interview today. I provided a multiary tree solution but it is not very efficient. I search google for this problem and many of them suggested union-find approach but did not provide code. I could not understand how it can be solved using union-find approach. Can you please help me how it can be solved using union find approach?

```
Design a data structure to support following functions:
1. setManager(A, B) sets A as a direct manager of B
2. setPeer(A, B) sets A as a colleague of B. After that, A and B will have the same direct Manager.
3. query(A, B) returns if A is in the management chain of B.
Every person only has 1 direct manager.
```

Comment: If A and B already have one manager each, what happens when calling `setPeer(A,B)`?

Comment: this is not valid input. please ignore this case.